# overrides scope multiple same component angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a component in angularjs that I want to use several times. This component has a multiselect inside (http://dotansimha.github.io/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/docs/#/main). So I have defined my component:

```
angular.module('app')
    .component('filtros', {
        templateUrl: './filtros.html',
        bindings: {
        },
        controller: ['$scope', '$http', '$translate', filtrosController]
    });

function filtrosController($scope, $http, $translate) {
    $scope.multiselectConfig = {
        model: [],
        data: [],
        settings: { checkBoxes: true },
        text: {
            checkAll: $translate.instant('checkAll'),
            uncheckAll: $translate.instant('uncheckAll'),
            buttonDefaultText: $translate.instant('buttonDefaultText'),
            dynamicButtonTextSuffix: $translate.instant('dynamicButtonTextSuffix')
        }
    };
      $scope.config.filtro = {
        tipo: {
            titulo: "Tipo",
            apiUrl: api.tipo,
            multiselect: {
                config: $scope.multiselectConfig
            }
        },
        estado: {
            titulo: "Estado",
            apiUrl: api.estado,
            multiselect: {
                config: $scope.multiselectConfig
            }
        }
    };


angular.module('app')
    .component('filtroSimple', {
        templateUrl: './filtroSimple.html',
        bindings: {
            config: '<'
        },
        controllerAs: '$ctrl',
        controller: ['$scope', '$http', '$translate', filtroSimpleController]
    });

function filtroSimpleController($scope, $http, $translate) {
    var $ctrl = this.config;
    $ctrl.fn = {
        cargarFiltro: cargarFiltro
    };

    $ctrl.fn.cargarFiltro();

    function cargarFiltro() {
        $http.get($ctrl.apiUrl)
            .then(function (response) {
                if (response.data) {
                    $ctrl.multiselect.config.data = response.data;
                }
            });
    }
}

<filtro-simple config="config.filtro.tipo"></filtro-simple>
<filtro-simple config="config.filtro.estado"></filtro-simple>
```

In the end, the result is that both components have the data of the last component. That is, in the first states were loaded, and in the second states were also loaded (although seeing the execution step by step, the first receives the Type data well).

Why are the values overwritten?

EDIT: I've made a test in Plunkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/QSrlr4nHR4yh2cmEqR2y?p=preview

Comment: can you add a snippet ?

Comment: Ok, I'll try to post it later. But I've tested with select-options and it runs ok, so the problem is with the multiselect-dropdown plugin